# How to wait for Google Form script to finish execution before executing Google sheet script in sheet linked to the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, race-condition

I have two scripts. One linked to a Google form and another linked to Google sheets. I need to make sure the Google Form script finishes execution before executing the body of the Google sheet script for a sheet linked to the Google Form. How can this be done?'

The wait on the Google Form script completion is needed as shown in the code below. I cannot use the `Utilities.sleep` as it may lead to a race condition depending on the timing of the execution.

```
//SCRIPT LINKED TO FORM
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 //does something
 return;
}
```

```
//SCRIPT LINKED TO SHEET
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 // Need to wait here until SCRIPT LINKED TO FORM finishes execution
 return;
}
```

Comment: Share your code, as a two-liner is insufficient to provide the contextual information needed to understand your issue. Please also describe what you have done and where the error lies, if possible.

Comment: The trigger `onFormSubmit()` fires **after** the linked form was submitted. This is the very point of the trigger. Probably your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I know trigger fires after submission. I need to wait until the Google Form script completes. Is it possible?

Comment: Why? Can you describe a use case?

Comment: I made some guesses and updated your  question. If it doesn't accurately describe your issue, kindly [edit] your question.

Comment: There's no out of the box way. If there's something specific that your //SCRIPT LINKED TO FORM does, we might be able to hook onto that. Alternatively, you may be able to put up a file in drive that says success or something like that. It's also possible to just create a artificial web api and hook onto it. Depends on your use case.

Comment: This is needed to workaround an issue which I already reported to Google with Google Form checkboxes. When such form is used with "Allow response editing" set to On and "Limit to 1 response" set to On the data in the sheet does not match submitted data in the form when a user does not select any of the checkboxes. In such case data from previous submission stays in the sheet. I need to be able to correct it by updating the sheet (clearing old data in it) using the Google Form script and executing the sheet's script only after that update is completed.

Comment: Don't think that's possible. Even if you rectify  the `response` using Google forms script, the response sent to Google sheets script won't change. It'll only receive the original response. Maybe wait longer to avoid race: Receive response in Google sheets > Create a trigger with response id for `after` 1 hour or so > When the script  is finally triggered, directly check the forms response with that id and update the sheet accordingly.

Comment: I already implemented the correcting of the data using the Google Form script and it does the correction. The issue is that I do not believe it will always work due to the potential for race condition. That is why I am looking for a way to find a method to wait for the finishing of the Google Form script in the Google sheet script. If such method is not available I will need to move to a different company to implement the site.

Comment: Look into [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en). Publish the sheets script as a webapp and make a `Urlfetchapp` request from the forms script after it completes. https://chat.stackoverflow.com//transcript/message/53266763#53266763

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it than developing webapp? It is not an effective workaround. Does Google plan to support synchronization mechanism between the Google Form script and Google sheet script in the future?

Comment: @Julia Although it's called web app, it's just one function `doPost()` no html, no js, nothing. It's just a simple api. Also, without a [mcve], We are not really sure what you're doing. Kindly post your script.

Answer (score 2):

You indicated that you have multiple forms linking to a common spreadsheet, and that each form has its own bound script. The issue you describe is that several scripts may possibly get triggered simultaneously and so can end up racing to update the same spreadsheet. The spreadsheet additionally has a bound script that runs on a form submit trigger as well.

Instead of trying to coordinate the timing of many different script projects, implement all the functionality in one script project that handles them all.

Use a [standalone script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that gets invoked by a number of Forms [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `on submit` triggers — one trigger per form.

The one script should update both the form data, and also the spreadsheet. Use the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) to ensure that at any given moment you are only running one instance of the code that writes data to the spreadsheet.

You can access the spreadsheet from the script that is bound to the form like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(60 * 1000);
  const form = e.source;
  // ...adjust form response data in the form's response store
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId());
  // ...adjust form response data in the spreadsheet
  lock.releaseLock();
  // ...send email
}
```

This code assumes that the update process always finishes within one minute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot implement all the functionality in the script that is bound to the form because I have multiple forms linking to a common sheet. I also need to send emails from the script. I am not sure it is possible to send GmailApp emails from the script bound to the form.

Comment: In that case, you will have to use a [standalone script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) and the the [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock). `GMailApp` is available in this context. The email will get sent from the account that installed the trigger. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The script in the one sheet is protected from multiple simultaneous executions using LockService.getScriptLock() on entry and lock.releaseLock(); on all exits. My understanding is that it should be sufficient to prevent race conditions within the script itself.

Comment: That's good, but the lock in the spreadsheet script will not help you coordinate with the other scripts that are bound to the forms. A lock will only be active in the script project where it is created. To coordinate between multiple script projects, you would need a "global" mutex. It would be a lot simpler to use one script for all.

Comment: Only two forms have checklists and need to have scripts to workaround the bug. They operate on different sheets in the spreadsheet so there is no need to coordinate them as far as I know. Having one common script for all forms would help with inability to reliably synchronize form scripts and the spreadsheet script. In order for this solution to work there needs to be a way to reliably wait for sheet to be updated after form submission before executing form script which corrects the submission. I filed separate question for it and am waiting for response on how this can be done (#69607724).